# How do you write / represent the 'all ones matrix'?

Tags: matrices, notation, convention

Is there a convention to write the all ones matrix in formulas? I'm going to write about the following formular:

$$
A = B + XD + DX + N
$$

Where D is a diagonal matrix and X the all ones matrix:

$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there a greek letter or other convention?

Comment: You could write $\mathbf1\mathbf1^\top$, where $\mathbf1$ is the vector with all components $1$.

Comment: I have seen it written as J, for example, by people who discuss incidence matrices of projective planes. The incidence matrix $A$ of a projective  plane of order $n$ satisfies $A^{t}A = AA^{t} = nI +J,$ and $AJ = JA = nJ.$

Comment: [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitMatrix.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones) both seem to use $J$. I'm not sure if this is a set convention though since this overlaps with notation for the Jordan form.

Comment: Unit matrix "J" will do. Thank you!

Comment: A related question on MathOverflow: [Why is the matrix of all 1's called “J”?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/321582)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I have seen the $n\times n$ all-ones matrix denoted $J_n$.  I think this is somewhat conventional in algebraic combinatorics, but I have no idea whether it is commonly used elsewhere.